# How do I get the average of each similar column value?

Tags: sql, oracle

Say I have this:

```
     tag     value

1    apple    3

2    banana   5

3    apple    4

4    banana   2
```

How can I have a query get the average of each value with respect to the tags?

So like:

```
    tag      value

1   apple    3.5

2   banana   3.5
```

I can get the average of the whole column easily with an inner select, but have no idea how to do so with respect to the tag.

Comment: Simple `AVG()` and `GROUP BY`... Try to use Google first. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions003.htm#SQLRF20035

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `group by` and `avg()`:

```
select
     tag
    ,avg(value)
from yourTable
group by tag
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach is to `group by` the tag and use the `avg()` function:

```
SELECT AVG(value) FROM table
GROUP BY tag
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with all of the above replies. I am adding ***dense rank function***. you can try it just for your understanding.
***Query:***

SELECT tag,
  value,
  avg(value) over (partition by tag) tot_avgerage,
  DENSE_RANK() 
  OVER (PARTITION BY tag order by value asc) AS drank
  FROM
  TABLE  ;